# How to do it horizontal scroll plugin JetSmartFilter Visual on Elementor?

Tags: filter, elementor

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/3coVB.png)

I installed je smartfilter visual on the site, how do I make this filter horizontal and scroll on the mobile version?

Inserting this css did not help:

```
selector ul {
     white-space: nowrap;
    overflow-x: auto; 
    overflow-y: hidden;
    flex-wrap: inherit !important;
    scrollbar-width: none; 
}
 
selector ul::-webkit-scrollbar { 
  display: none; 
}
```